# C++ class inheritance and member functions

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

All,
I am having difficulty understanding why I am getting the following error.  I promise this is not a homework problem, but I am new to C++!  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Base {
protected:
  std::string label;
public:
  Base(std::string _label) : label(_label) { }
  std::string get_label() { return label; }
};

class Derived : private Base {
private:
  std::string fancylabel;
public:
  Derived(std::string _label, std::string _fancylabel)
   : Base{_label}, fancylabel{_fancylabel} { }
  std::string get_fancylabel() { return fancylabel; }
};

class VecDerived {
private:
  std::vector<Derived> vec_derived;
public:
  VecDerived(int n)
  {
    vec_derived = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      Derived newDerived(std::to_string(i), std::to_string(2*i));
      vec_derived.push_back(newDerived);
    }
  }
  std::string get_label(int n)  { return vec_derived.at(n).get_label(); }
  std::string get_fancylabel(int n) { return vec_derived.at(n).get_fancylabel(); }
};

int main (void)
{
  VecDerived obj(5);
  std::cout << obj.get_label(2) << " " << obj.get_fancylabel(2) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler error I get is as follows:

```
test1.cpp: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string VecDerived::get_label(int)’:
test1.cpp:33:70: error: ‘std::__cxx11::string Base::get_label()’ is inaccessible within this context
   std::string get_label(int n)  { return vec_derived.at(n).get_label(); }
                                                                  ^
test1.cpp:9:15: note: declared here
   std::string get_label() { return label; }
               ^~~~~~~~~
test1.cpp:33:70: error: ‘Base’ is not an accessible base of ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Derived> >::value_type {aka Derived}’
   std::string get_label(int n)  { return vec_derived.at(n).get_label(); }
```

I don't understand why the member function get_label() wasn't inherited from the Base class to the Derived class, such that I'm not able to access it via the VecDerived class.  Is there a way that this can be resolved?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why did you choose private inheritance is you want the inherited stuff to be public?

Comment: >Is there a way that this can be resolved? 
yes, public inheritance

Comment: problem with questions about homework is that too often they contain too little information, ask others to write the code without showing any effort, and similar. Asking about homework is nothing bad per se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio emits an error message that gives you more hints:

> error C2247: 'Base::get_label' not accessible because 'Derived' uses 'private' to inherit from 'Base'

So if you want to access `Base::get_label` through a `Derived` object, then you either need to make the base class public:

```
class Derived : public Base
```

or make `get_label` public:

```
class Derived : private Base {
public:
    using Base::get_label;
```

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks, fixed it :).

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.  Thanks!